# Bash completion not working when environment variable defined

Tags: bash, tab-completion, bash-completion

When I define an environment variable inline like this: `env_variable=true command`, my custom bash completion script fails. Example:

```
user@host in /tmp/tmp.6DRvQAkpFe
> ls
user@host in /tmp/tmp.6DRvQAkpFe
> docker-ssh 
container1 container2 container3 puppetmaster           
user@host in /tmp/tmp.6DRvQAkpFe
> VARIABLE=TEST docker-ssh
```

The last command doesn't autocomplete like the one before it.

My bash completion function looks like this:

```sh
_docker-ssh() {
    local running=$(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}') 
    local cur prev opts base

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${running}" -- ${cur}))

    return 0
}

complete -F _docker-ssh docker-ssh
```

Is there something I'm missing in my `COMPREPLY` that would take into account environment variables?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in any way. Use `set -x` inside the function to check the actual values.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. As a side note, you don't need your function, you can reduce the second code block to `complete -W '$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}")' docker-ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is a feature [introduced](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.3#n65) in bash 4.3.

> The command completion code skips whitespace and assignment statements before looking for the command name word to be completed.